# Mocking method taking a Supplier<String> method not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, functional-programming, mockito

Given the following classes:

```
class Logger {
  public void log(String someInfo,
                  String someOtherInfo,
                  VssNotificationStatus status,
                  Supplier<String> message)
  {}
}

class Asset {
  private String name;
  private String alias;

  Asset(String name, String alias) {
    this.name = name;
    this.alias = alias;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
  }
}

class ClassUnderTest {
  private Logger logger;

  ClassUnderTest(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public void methodUnderTest(Asset asset) {
    logger.log(asset.getName(), asset.getAlias(), VssNotificationStatus.ASSET_PREPARED, () -> String.format("%s is running", "methodUnderTest"));
  }
}
```

And the following test code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {
  private ClassUnderTest clazz;
  @Mock
  private Logger logger;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    clazz = new ClassUnderTest(logger);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // given
    String info1 = "info1";
    String info2 = "info2";
    Asset asset = mock(Asset.class);
    given(asset.getName()).willReturn(info1);
    given(asset.getAlias()).willReturn(info2);

    // when
    clazz.methodUnderTest(asset);

    // then
    verify(logger).log(eq(asset.getName()), eq(asset.getAlias()), eq(VssNotificationStatus.ASSET_PREPARED), any());
  }
}
```

fails at the `verify` line with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded
```

I tried to use `isA(Supplier.class)`, specify `Supplier.class` in the `any` method, but still same error. It feels like Mockito is not mocking properly this method.

Those failing tests were passing properly before refactoring the last parameter from simple `String` parameter to a `Supplier<String>`.

I'm using mockito-core 2.13.0

Comment: Above code works for me without any issues

Comment: The exception you have mentioned happens only if 1. Logger is a final class or 2. The object you are calling (logger) is not a mock or not properly initialized as a mock

Comment: Interesting... My simple example is also working without issues. So it's most definitely something in my real test...

Comment: As I mentioned above. It could happen in one of the above cases. Sorry for the confused answer. I deleted that.  Recheck your real tests

Comment: See my updated question (reproducing the error) and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Matchers doesn't like when you pass in a mocked method instead of using the value you used when mocking this method directly. The following `verify` works perfectly fine.

```
verify(logger).log(eq(info1), eq(info2), eq(VssNotificationStatus.ASSET_PREPARED), any());
```

So matchers should use real values and not getting them from a mocked object.